# ¿Como cambiar los datos que vienen cargados de un dropdownlist de asp.net mvc con JQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dropdownlist, filtro

Que tal a todos tengo un problema con un dropdownlist, quiero hacer un filtrado de datos por los siguientes estatus:
-Activo
-Rechazado
-Pendiente

pero el dropdownlist que tengo cargado ya me hace el filtrado correspondiente es solo que me carga los valores de la base de datos los cuales son tynint.

```
<div class="text-center">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "SalidaPersonas", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "input-group" }))
    {
        @Html.DropDownList("filtrado", null, "Filtrar por", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "filtro" })

        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="submit" value="Filtrar" class="btn btn-group btn-primary ml-1" />
        </span>
    }
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera convertir los valores en lo siguiente:

1 => Activo

2 => Rechazado

3 => Pendiente

Existe alguna forma de que se pueda realizar con JQuery, ¿me podrían apoyar? De antemano gracias.

Comment: No es necesario usar Jquery para hacer lo que necesitas, la mejor manera de hacerlo es utilizando las propiedades de el dropdownlist ya te deje una respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo solucioné de la siguiente, en un ViewBag cargué una lista con los elementos.

```
        ViewBag.filtrado = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value="1", Text ="Aprobado" },
            new SelectListItem { Value="2", Text= "Rechazado"},
            new SelectListItem { Value="3", Text = "Pendiente"}
        };
```

tiene que tener el mismo nombre que el ViewBag que me trae los datos.

```
        ViewBag.filtrado = new SelectList(db.SALIDAPERSONA.Select(m => m.EstatusPermiso).Distinct());
```

Comment: Esta bien aunque es muy poco optimo que realices una consulta a BD y luego asignes las descripciones en el CodeBehind de tu proyecto. Recuerda programar de manera modular, para que puedas realizar cambios a tu programa de manera efectiva sin necesidad de afectar tu código.

Answer (score 1):

`SelectList` es un helper Html de Asp.net al cual se le pueden pasar un grupo de parámetros para lograr lo que deseas sin tener que pasar tanto trabajo. Debes leer los parámetros que este acepta y entenderás su funcionamiento. ejemplo:

```
 SelectList(System.Collections.IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField, object selectedValue, string dataGroupField);
```

El 1er parámetro es una colección de objetos (Son todos los objetos que se mostrarán en el desplegable de tu vista HTML, Aqui se puede declarar hasta una consulta LINQ que retorne una lista).

El 2do parámetro es un string ejemplo: "id" y es el valor que vas a recoger al seleccionar un objeto del desplegable, en este caso el Id.

El 3er parámetro es otro string y representa el texto que se mostrará para cada objeto del desplegable en tu vista HTML. ejemplo "Nombre".

El 4to mostrará un item seleccionado por defecto. (Muy utilizado en  la vista Edit donde debes mostrar el valor que  ya tiene ese objeto por defecto)

El 5to para definir el grupo al que pertenece en caso de que se hallan definido grupos. (En lo personal no he trabajado mucho con este parámetro).

una vez explicado esto te pongo un ejemplo para que lo veas más claro.
Suponiendo que tienes una clase `Filtro` con los atributos `id` y `nombre` donde Id almacena los valores(1,2,3..) y nombre("Activo", "Rechazado", "Pendiente"...) o simplemente una lista llamada Filtros con esos valores y necesitas mostrarlos en tu HTML como un `Select` desplegable. basta con definirlo en tu controlador de la siguiente manera:

```
ViewBag.filtrado = new SelectList(db.Filtros(),"Id", "Nombre");
```

y en tu vista tal y como lo tenias declarado, fijándote de que coincidan los nombres del ViewBag y del primer parámetro del Helpler HTML.

```
@Html.DropDownList("filtrado", null, "Filtrar por", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "filtro" })
```

De esta forma al desplegar el select se mostrarán los nombres de los filtros pero al seleccionarlos pasarás el Id como value. Espero te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score -1):

Solo debes agregar un campo descripción en la tabla de tu base de datos y rellenar de esta manera:

```
ddl.DataSource = dt;
ddl.DataValueField = "ID";
ddl.DataTextField = "DESCRIPCION";
ddl.DataBind();
```

Donde **ddl** es tu dropdownlist y **dt** es el resultado de tu consulta a base de datos. **ID** es el nombre de tu columna asignada en base de datos con los valores y **DESCRIPCION** el nombre de la columna que guarda las descripciones.

Comment: Gracias intentaré de ésta manera.